# Why does my while loop work in the main file, but not if I try to include it from a separate file?

Tags: php, html, mysql, while-loop

I have a while loop that works exactly the same on three different pages. To make it easier to alter it, I put it in it's own php file, gmldLoop. However, after doing so and including gmldLoop where I'd like it to run on the file, g, it doesn't work. I'm not sure why this is happening. The code is exactly copied and pasted in both files, so I know it's not a typo.

The code that works on g.php:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM guidelines ORDER BY sortingLetter ASC, age ASC, category ASC";
$data= mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $age = $row['age'];
    $cat = $row['category'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $desc = $row['description'];
    $ageRange = $row['ageRange'];
    $sortingLetter = $row['sortingLetter'];

    ?>
    <section class="content 
        <?php 
            switch($ageRange){
                case 1:
                    echo "one";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    echo "one";
                    break;
                case 123456:
                    echo "all";
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    echo "two";
                    break;
                case 23:
                    echo "two three";
                    break;
                case 23456:
                    echo "two three four five six";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "three";
                    break;
                case 34:
                    echo "three four";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    echo "four";
                    break;
                case 45:
                    echo "four five";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    echo "five";
                    break;
                case 56:
                    echo "five six";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    echo "six";
                    break;
                case 0:
                    echo "all";
                    break;
            }
        ?>"
    >
        <h2 class="heading noborder">
            <div class="title textfloatL">
                <small><strong><?php echo $title; ?></strong></small>
            </div>

        </h2>

        <br><br>
        <div class="sqldata">
            <div class="desc">
                <?php echo $desc; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="agesdiv incap textfloatR">
                <p class="inup">
                    <small><?php if (!$age) {
                            echo 'All Ages';
                        } else {
                            echo $age;
                        } ?></small>
                </p>
                |
                <p class="incap">
                    <small><?php echo $cat; ?></small>
                </p>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php
 }
?>
```

The code from gmldLoop :

```
    $data= mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $age = $row['age'];
    $cat = $row['category'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $desc = $row['description'];
    $ageRange = $row['ageRange'];
    $sortingLetter = $row['sortingLetter'];

    ?>
    <section class="content 
        <?php 
            switch($ageRange){
                case 1:
                    echo "one";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    echo "one";
                    break;
                case 123456:
                    echo "all";
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    echo "two";
                    break;
                case 23:
                    echo "two three";
                    break;
                case 23456:
                    echo "two three four five six";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    echo "three";
                    break;
                case 34:
                    echo "three four";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    echo "four";
                    break;
                case 45:
                    echo "four five";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    echo "five";
                    break;
                case 56:
                    echo "five six";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    echo "six";
                    break;
                case 0:
                    echo "all";
                    break;
            }
        ?>"
    >
        <h2 class="heading noborder">
            <div class="title textfloatL">
                <small><strong><?php echo $title; ?></strong></small>
            </div>

        </h2>

        <br><br>
        <div class="sqldata">
            <div class="desc">
                <?php echo $desc; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="agesdiv incap textfloatR">
                <p class="inup">
                    <small><?php if (!$age) {
                            echo 'All Ages';
                        } else {
                            echo $age;
                        } ?></small>
                </p>
                |
                <p class="incap">
                    <small><?php echo $cat; ?></small>
                </p>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php
 }
?>
```

The code in g.php if I use the include 'gmldLoop.php' :

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM guidelines ORDER BY sortingLetter ASC, age ASC, category ASC";
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/inc/pageStructure/gmldLoop.php';
?>
```

Comment: do the sql variables such as db_conn exist in this context now? seems like the error log will contain your answer to this one

Comment: Nothing comes up in the error_log, that's the first place I looked. And yes, the db_conn is defined in the top of the page.

Comment: Try adding var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($data)); die(); to gmldLoop. This might give a clue to the cause

Comment: Nothing is showing up, you can see at www.mommy-info.com/all-about-baby/guidelines

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM guidelines ORDER BY sortingLetter ASC, age ASC, category ASC";
```

in gmldLoop file.

Comment: can you print what result we are getting?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but it's working now! www.mommy-info.com/guidelines